# In Eclipse, where do you find the option to automatically include chosen static imports?

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl

Last week I found a setting in Eclipse that allows you to automatically include chosen static imports even when they are not written out. I am creating a Java clone of my OpenGL + GLFW C++ engine over to Java and I want to be able to statically import all of the GL classes without having to specify each version to use a method.

I didn't really bother with the setting, but now that I want it I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is found under "Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites".

You can add a `New Type...` like `mylibrary.*` and everytime you press `Ctrl + Space`, Eclipse will show the matching static methods from `mylibrary`.